# Why is the epigraph of Moreau-Yosida Regularization a projection of a convex set?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, variational-analysis

The Moreau-Yosida Regularization is given by

\begin{equation}
f_\mu(x) = \inf_y \left( f(y) + \frac{1}{2\mu} \| x - y \|^2 \right).
\end{equation}

We know that $L(x, y) = f(y) + \frac{1}{2\mu} \| x - x \|^2$ is jointly convex in $x$ and $y$.

Source: https://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/math301/Lectures/Moreau-Yosida.pdf

Why is the epigraph of $f_\mu(x)$ a projection of a convex set?

Comment: Who claims it is a projection? I would rather call it the intersection of (infinitely many) convex sets.

Comment: The course note states that "$f_u(x)$'s epigraph is the projection of a convex set" on the first page.

Comment: I do not see how you get $\{(x,t) : \inf_y L(x,y) \leq t\}$ from a projection of $\{(x,y,t) : L(x,y) \leq t\}$. Ask the author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, this is a common mistake. It might be, of course, a projection of some convex set onto the $(x, t)$ coordinates, but it is not "the" convex set you might first think of.

Like any other 'infimal convolution', the epigraph of the Moreau-Yosida regularization is a sum of epigraphs. To be precise, it is the Minkowski sum of the epigraph of $f$ and the epigraph of $\frac{1}{2\mu}\|x\|_2^2$:
$$
\operatorname{epi}(f_\mu) = \operatorname{epi}(f)+\operatorname{epi}(\tfrac{1}{2\mu}\|\cdot\|_2^2) \equiv \{ (x+y, t+s) : (x, t) \in \operatorname{epi}(f),~(y, s) \in \operatorname{epi}(\tfrac{1}{2\mu}\|\cdot\|_2^2) \}
$$
See the excellent paper on [Epigraphical Analysis](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0294144917300367) by Attouch and Wets for more details. The sum of convex sets is convex, and that is one reason why $f_\mu$ is convex.